# Evaluating only values from a formula in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am able to execute a specific formula and assign it to a cell:

```
my_cell = Int(Cells(row, my_col).Value2) '# "row" is a row, "my_col" is a column, "i" is a counter
Cells(row, i).FormulaR1C1 = "=a working formula that returns a date as a number"
Cells(row, i).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy" '# format the number as a date
```

but I actually want to only write the value returned by the formula and not show the whole formula's syntax when selecting the destination cell.

I found this method and it works:

```
my_cell = Int(Cells(row, my_col).Value2)
Cells(row, i).FormulaR1C1 = "=a working formula that returns a date as a number"
Cells(row, i).Copy
Cells(row, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Cells(row, i).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

but it seems really slow (I have a lot of data) and not really performing as a solution since it copy-and-paste the value instead of directly evaluating and assigning it.

Is there a faster and more straightforward way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of worksheet function is available in VBA. The syntax is:

```
WorksheetFunction.SomeFunction(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

so, you could use following code:

```
With WorksheetFunction
    Cells(row, i)= 'Your formula, with function preceeded with dot .
End With
```

Some worksheet functions are not available this way, for instance LEFT, but usually there is equivalent VBA function, so you my type Left without dot.

Comment: I actually don't encounter any problem with writing the formula. I get the correct result in my destination cell, but my goal is not showing the formula in the destination cell (I just want to view the resulting value, not the formula).

Comment: But this solution do not paste formula, but result exactly. Like Range("B1") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A1:A5")) will insert sum of numerical values from A1 to A5 into cell B1.

Comment: I didn't completely understand your answer. I got it working, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you see the formula instead of only the result, maybe you have activated the option "Display Formula" on the Options Ribbon?

[image: Display Formulas]

To turn it off using VBA just type:

```
ActiveWindow.DisplayFormulas = False
```

Could it be?

Comment: +1 Thanks for the interest, but this should only "hide" formulas (but the will still appear if I activate the option again).